# Kafka Connect JDBC: custom SMT or simple chained SMT?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I was following those [tutorials](https://rmoff.net/2020/12/08/twelve-days-of-smt-day-1-insertfield-timestamp/) and I would like to do something more.
The environment I am using is the one suggested and can be found in this [Github page](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-connect-single-message-transforms) under docker-compose.yaml.

I would like to modify a bit the [second tutorial](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-connect-single-message-transforms/day2.adoc).
The author gives instructions to load rows in a simple table:

```
create table customers (
id INT,
full_name VARCHAR(50),
birthdate DATE,
fav_animal VARCHAR(50),
fav_colour VARCHAR(50),
fav_movie VARCHAR(50)
);

insert into customers (id, full_name, birthdate, fav_animal, fav_colour, fav_movie) values (1, 'Leone Puxley', '1995-02-06', 'Violet-eared waxbill', 'Puce', 'Oh! What a Lovely War');
insert into customers (id, full_name, birthdate, fav_animal, fav_colour, fav_movie) values (2, 'Angelo Sharkey', '1996-04-08', 'Macaw, green-winged', 'Red', 'View from the Top, A');

(... more inserts..)
```

After that it creates a simple jdbc source connector and push data into a kafka topic.
Later on it shows the content of the topic in Avro format:

```
 {
  "topic": "mysql-00-customers",
  "partition": 0,
  "offset": 0,
  "tstype": "create",
  "ts": 1607512308962,
  "broker": 1,
  "key": null,
  "payload": {
    "id": {
      "int": 1
    },
    "full_name": {
      "string": "Leone Puxley"
    },
    "birthdate": {
      "int": 9167
    },
    "fav_animal": {
      "string": "Violet-eared waxbill"
    },
    "fav_colour": {
      "string": "Puce"
    },
    "fav_movie": {
      "string": "Oh! What a Lovely War"
    }
  }
 }
```

I would like a simpler payload like this:

```
"payload": {
        "id":1,
        "full_name": "Leone Puxley",
        "birthdate": 9167,
        "fav_animal": "Violet-eared waxbill",
        "fav_colour": "Puce",
        "fav_movie": "Oh! What a Lovely War"
        }
```

I thought about using [flatten](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html#flatten) and then [replace field](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html#replacefield) but I have two problems: the message in the topic does not change after applying the flatten transform and moreover I don't like this solution because if a message has 100 fields I should specify ~ 200 transforms.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing to flatten/transform. That format with the fields types is Avro-specific

Comment: Can you edit your question to elaborate on *why* you want to do this? As in, what's the next step with the data that you're wanting to do that you're being hampered by at the moment?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am aware that the format is Avro specific as reported https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/jdbc_connector.html#quickstart here , but the payload is a bit redundant isn't it? Is there a way to obtain the payload I mentioned?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt thanks for replying, it is a pleasure to read the author of the very well done tutorials! I would like to remove redundant fields in order to simplify future transformation. I am using Kafka between a Sink and a Source and I am exploring some data-transformation possibilities

Comment: It is not redundant because your database columns are nullable, thus the types are necessary for avro to distinguish. If you want to really get the "flattened" data, you'd likely need to put `NOT NULL` properties on your database fields. Also, if using AvroConverter in any downstream sinks, then the types are still necessary

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer for your answer! I got another doubt, I tried to consume from the same topic with a simple python client like this one: https://github.com/skyrocknroll/python-kafka-avro-example. If I print the value of the message got with an AvroDeserializer the output (I did not modify the print in the code mentioned in the link above) is like the one I described in the question. Why this difference? 

Moreover it seems to me that the type information is already in the schema, why it has to be on the payload as well?

Comment: I am not familiar with how Python's Avro libraries work, but I'm guessing you're getting a dict, rather than a plain Avro object

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you so much! I was noticing that the output I gave in the question was obtained using kcat that performs an Avro to Json conversion as highlighted in the kcat examples (https://github.com/edenhill/kcat#examples). Maybe the conversion automatically adds the type?

Comment: For nullable types, yes

Comment: You can refer the JSON Spec here - https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schemas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237327/discussion-between-cr4zytun4-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: @OneCricketeer the link you provided is regarding schema only. Not the message payload itself. I thought some answer could be in how the data is deserialized from bytes to JSON but could not found any reference

Comment: Under JSON Encoding - "encoded as a JSON object with one name/value pair whose **name is the type's name** and whose **value is the recursively encoded value**"